# AngularJS Merge two page application in to one page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a two-page application which gets the user input for the query in one page and displays the result in the grid on the other page. I am trying to merge this application into one page where user input at the top of the page and result in the grid bottom of the page. I am very new to Angular/ Javascripting. I can call the next page on the button on the `ng-click` event but not sure how to display on the same page. Below is the code for the two-page application

home.html

```
<div>
  <form name="homeForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
      <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">Laboratory Name</label>
        <select name="labName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.labName" required>
          <option ng-repeat="lab in labList" value="{{lab.id}}">{{lab.value}}</option>
        </select>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.labName.$error" ng-if="homeForm.labName.$touched">
          <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Views/Angular/results.html" ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

result.html

```
<div>
  <h4 class="text-primary">Search Results</h4>
  <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-around">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoading" md-diameter="150"></md-progress-circular>
  </div>
  <div id="gridStyle" ng-if="gridOptions.data" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-exporter>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the controllers looks something like below

homeController.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module("app").controller("homeController", homeController);

  function homeController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window) {
    .........
    $scope.createRequest = function(form) {
      $rootScope.labName = $scope.request.labName;
      $location.path('/results');
    };
  };
})();
```

resultController.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module("app").controller("resultsController", resultsController);

  function resultsController($scope, $http, $rootScope,
    uiGridConstants) {

    ....

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
      name: 'RequestID',
      displayName: "Request ID",
      enableColumnResizing: true,
      width: 100
    }];
    var myQuery = "SELECT submitter from request where lab = '" + rootScope.labName + "'";
    var params = {
      query: myQuery
    };

    $http.get('/api/AtRequest', {
        params: params
      })
      .then(
        function(response) {
          $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
          $scope.isLoading = false;
        },
        function(response) {
          console.log("Something went wrong");
        }
      );
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to merge.
One of them is to use ng-include tag in your home.html file and this add your grid to home.html file (consider the correct path for result.html file and don't use ng-controller in result.html)

```
<div ng-include="'result.html'"></div>
```

remove href from button and handle ng-click to fill grid's data

then merge controllers( add content of resultController to homeController).

If you want to separate the file of controllers from each other, you can create a service which fetch data and call it in your homeController.

Comment: I tried doing that when I merge the result and home controller it does work. I throws 404 error. Can you please give me an example how to merge it

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this, but be aware you should have only one ng-controller in this file and in this sample it is homeController. 
If you have 404 error, it is probably because of path of result.html.check if it is in the correct path that you assigned it to ng-include or not.

```
<div ng-controller=homeController>
<form name="homeForm">
<div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
  <div>
    <label style="font-size: medium">Laboratory Name</label>
    <select name="labName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.labName" required>
      <option ng-repeat="lab in labList" value="{{lab.id}}">{{lab.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.labName.$error" ng-if="homeForm.labName.$touched">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
    <div class="row form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Views/Angular/results.html" 
   ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-include="'result.html'"></div>
 </form>
</div>
```